# How do I delete menu item created by createAddonMenu() in Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, menuitem

I created an add-on menu for Google Sheet by using script `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()`. But as requested by our customer, instead of putting this menu under Add-ons, now we put this menu on top menu by using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().CreateMenu()` and want to remove the menu under Add-ons. I tried `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().removeMenu()` but it doesn't work. Is anyone know how to remove the Add-ons menu item?

Answer (score 3):

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().removeMenu('Custom Menu');

Reloading the Spreadsheet with Ctrl + R doesn't work to re-execute onOpen(), because the Spreadsheet App overrides the keys' function and reloads the Spreadsheet content within the Google App. To really reload, you may press Ctrl + F5 or use the Browser's Reload button or click into the address bar and hit Enter.

Some Examples for creating, editing and removing menus / menu items:

http://apps-script-google.blogspot.com/2015/03/custom-menu-create-delete.html

Answer (score 2):

I realized the SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu() was in onOpen(), that means this Add-on menu item was only created when the sheet is opening. That means if the sheet is closed, the menu item will not exist. So just modify menu items in the script, close the sheet and re-open it, the menu item will be change accordingly.